# Connection string not passed as function argument

Tags: php, function, connection

I have a page (index.php) that imports connections using require_once. The problem is that when i pass the connection string using $connectobject1 variable as function argument, it works in some functions but does not in others on the same page.

Any specific thing that i'm missing which is resulting it to work in only some functions of the same page.

here is the code for index.php:

```
require_once '../connect/db_connect.php';

function check1 ($connectobject1,$Id)
{

    function code..
}

function check2 ($connectobject1,$User)
{

    function code..
}
```

strangely for `check2` the `$connectobject1` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Show the relevant code; Give us a [mcve]

Comment: Make sure you don't overwrite or close the connection before you pass it to the second function.

Comment: @Rizier123 - What can i say. People always overlook the obvious. I was doing exactly the same. Thanks1

Comment: That is why you need to try to isolate the problem and reproduce the error on another environment. So you can track down errors like this easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will follow going forward.